# Why I set the leading ,top ,trailing constraint of a UILabel ,the Label constraint still exceed the constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

```
[self addConstraint:[self.statusLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.avatar.leadingAnchor constant:0]];
[self addConstraint:[self.statusLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.avatar.bottomAnchor constant:10 priority:999]];
[self addConstraint:[self.statusLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor constant:-10]];
```

This is the view debugger snapshot

[image: This is the view debugger snapshot]

Comment: You steel have errors?

Comment: Yes,I have a view hierarchy that the cell have a container view,and the container view have the label.At first I set the container's constraint to satisfy the dynamic cell require.Then I set the Label's constraint to the container.The is actually have multi lines,but the label's content width is not as sam as the width constraint.

Comment: You should add label constraint to cell content view